# Laravel Not able to dispatch job from crontab

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, jobs

if i use this code in a controller queuing works well

```
 $job=(new ReProcessShipment($single_data->request_data))->delay(2);
 $this->dispatch($job);
```

but using same code in crontab error throws

> Method App\Console\Commands\AddPreProcess::dispatch does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0):
>   Method App\Console\Commands\AddPreProcess::dispatch does not exist.

tried to use it like

```
 $job=(new ReProcessShipment($single_data->request_data))->delay(2);
 ReProcessShipment::dispatch($job);
```

then get error

> Object of class App\Jobs\ReProcessShipment could not be converted to string {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class App\Jobs\ReProcessShipment could not be converted to string at

am not able to process job queue from a cronjob any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [dispatch](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dispatching-jobs) a job by calling static `dispatch` method on the job class and passing the job's constructor arguments to the `dispatch` method, like this:

```
ReProcessShipment::dispatch($single_data->request_data)->delay(2);
```

Ensure that you are using the `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable` trait to be able to call `dispatch` on the job class, e.g.:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, ...
```

If you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php#L14) you'll see that the static `dispatch` function creates the job for you using the job's parameters, so you don't need to create the job before you dispatch it. This is the source of the `dispatch` function:

```
public static function dispatch()
{
    return new PendingDispatch(new static(...func_get_args()));
}
```

So it essentially transforms this:

```
ReProcessShipment::dispatch($single_data->request_data);
```

into this:

```
new PendingDispatch(new ReProcessShipment($single_data->request_data));
```

Comment: In your second example you're passing the `$job` to the `dispatch` method. In my example above I'm passing the job's parameters to the `dispatch` method.

Comment: You're doing `dispatch($job);`, I'm suggesting `dispatch($single_data->request_data)`.